# Use Xpath to get all the rows of a table after a specific row in Automation Anywhere

Tags: xpath, automationanywhere

I am trying to get the values of all the row after a specific row(This specific row can be identified using id) using xpath. Kindly note that i am using it in automation anywhere's object cloning command to locate and fetch the details.
lets say this is the table:

```
<table class="actiontable" >
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr id="h32423">
<td class="claim"><span id="claimants">Claimants</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="a23">
<td id="g543"><a href="some site">Edward Hunter</a> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="g544"><a href="some site">Jane Doe</a> </td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here in the above table I need to fetch all the name after the Claimants row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: I used the below one but it brings every <tr> , but i want what is after claimants //table[@class="actionTable"]/descendant::tr

Comment: Check answer i update your XPath

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `preceding-sibling` data like this:

```
//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[normalize-space(.)='Claimants']]
```

You can try this as per your comment:

```
/table[@class='actiontable']/descendant::tr[normalize-space(lower-case(.))!= 'claimants']
```

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example you can do the following in the Automation Anywhere editor:

Add a loop command with a `Times` condition of `2`

Inside the loop object clone one of the  fields you want to access and change the `DOMXPath` to

```
/html/body/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[$Counter$+3]/td[1]/a[1]
```

Select `Action` to be `Get Property` and `Select Property` to `HTML InnerText`
Assign this to a variable of your choice

Output this variable via a message box command

When run you should then see displayed the two names.

In this we are using the AA counter variable to iterate through the DOMXPath. I have adjusted it by 3 as there are 3 `<tr>` tags before the row you wish to start on

Comment: The problem is it is not always 2. The number of rows after claimants varies dynamically. So I cannot iterate it 2 times, all the time.

Comment: As mentioned this was for your simple example. You have a few strategies you can follow to get the count. a) Clone the table and get the total rows (you will need to adjust this to get the starting position b) change the loop to a condition and then wrap the object cloning in an error handler in which you set your condition. This means it will loop through all the rows until it doesn't work and then exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's too late to answer or not. I think the following XPath match your condition.

`//tr[td[span[@id='claimants']]]/following-sibling::tr/td/a`

*You can change `/tr/td/a` to `/tr` or `/tr/td` according to which element you want to access

I try this XPath in *XPath Search console* on Google Chrome and it navigate to all `a` tags after the row which has ID = *claimants*.

As I'm quite new to AA, I don't know how to loop through those a tags getting from the XPath. But I hope this help you solve the problem. :)

**[Update]** I found the solution
1. Using `//tr[td[span[@id='claimants']]]` with Object Cloning to get the index of the specific row. Let's say the index value is stored in variable `$vIndex$`
2. Loop through all `td` in the table
3. If the `$Counter$` > `$vIndex$` THEN that is the row under the specific row.