# Get Title of html file which is downloaded on my machine in automation anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

I'm a newbie and this is my first try at Automation anywhere bot building.

I need to get the title of a html file downloaded on my machine.

So, basically I need to traverse the html and get title.

I found questions like [Use Xpath to get all the rows of a table after a specific row in Automation Anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314467/use-xpath-to-get-all-the-rows-of-a-table-after-a-specific-row-in-automation-anyw/53316370) which speak of xpath and html traversal.

But, I cant seem to find any article which says how to get source code of a html file in my computer. Nor, where to put these xpath codes.
Maybe everyone knows and as I'm a new, I can't figure it out.

This is what I tried...

I renamed the file to xml and tried to start a xml session and get the node //html/title

But it throws the below error at start session.

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround would be: rename the file to text and read the title from it.

1. Rename HTML file to TXT file.
2. Using **Read From CSV/Text** command read the text file.
3. Within the loop, use **if condition on variable**, FileDataColumn(1) if includes `<title>`
4. **Using string operation before and after** command, Before: `<title>` After: `</title>` and assign the output to a variable, and that would be the HTML title.

[image]

Comment: Great, this will work for title but I was hoping to get a soln for xpath traversal as tomorrow I might need something else than title. Is there a place where I can run xpath on the txt file as you stated

Comment: Also some html files come compressed with no spaces or enter between tags..

Comment: This will work even if your entire HTML is in one line. you are basically extracting text between the title tags ignoring everything else

Comment: @Tanmay Gawankar correct, that because of the string operation before and after command.

Comment: @KhaledMostafaMe I find that if my html document has non english unicode characters in the title, and I rename it to a .txt file, they become junk when I use this code. The same thing happens if I save the file manually as a .txt file. But the strange thing is if I create a .txt file and copy-paste the contents of the html file manually into it, and then run the code, it works perfectly. Any ideas why??

Comment: @Arnab checking for an update. Did you solve the above mentioned encoding issue? Just wanted solution if i face any same issue in future.

Comment: Additionally, why didn't you use Read from Text file directly on HTML file

Comment: Because read from csv/text file only works on csv/text files.

Comment: @TanmayGawankar The above soln will work provided the title open and close tags are in same line, but this is with earlier version of automation anywhere. With the new version, some changes will be needed.

Comment: @arnab Yes, with A2019 it will be different